# Where can I download GNOME Shell themes?

Tags: themes, gnome

I was wondering if there was anywhere that I could download gnome3's gnome-shell themes?

I have got gnome3 running perfectly on natty, Just want a different theme!

Comment: I'm lazy today so I'll just post 2 links as a comment and not an answer: How to change GNOME 3 (GNOME Shell Or Classic) GTK / Mutter / Metacity Theme: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/change-gnome-3-gnome-shell-or-classic.html and ThemeSelector: GNOME Shell Extension To Change Themes (With Previews): http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/themeselector-gnome-shell-extension-to.html - comes with 5 themes by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a GNOME Shell group on Deviant Art, where you can find a lot of useful stuff. [GNOME Shell Themes Gallery on Deviant Art.](http://gnome-shell.deviantart.com/gallery/28081982)

Answer (score 1):

[GNOME-Look.org](http://gnome-look.org/) has a [whole section](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=191) devoted to GNOME Shell themes.